# example of opengl surface apps in android

Tags: android, opengl-es, surfaceview

i am developing one app using opengl surface view ,how can implemented please forward some example  android apps using open gl surface

Comment: Have you took a look at the Api Demos in the SDK?

Comment: opengl surface  related some android gamming  books

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.cs.uccs.edu/~semwal/indexGLTutorial.html this url related open gl surface